# Using closed graph theorem to show that a map is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume that $0<a<1$ and let $X$ be a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ such that each $f\in X$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,1)$.

I am trying to show that the operator (it might not be)
$D: X \rightarrow C[0,a] $ given by $D(f) = f'|_{[0,a]}$ is a closed graph.

My idea was to take a sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty \rightarrow 0$ in $X$ and $(f_n' \rightarrow y)$ in $C[0,a]$ and show that $y=0$. But at the moment I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you say your idea was is not what you need to do to  show the graph is closed! You need to show this:

If $f_n\to f$ in $X$ and $f_n'\to g$ in $C[0,a]$ then $f'=g$.

Which is precisely a result from advanced calculus: If $f_n\to f$ uniformly and $f_n'\to g$ uniformly then $f'=g$. Seems to me the simplest proof is to note that $$f_n(x)-f_n(0)=\int_0^x f_n'(t)\,dt,$$so $f_n'\to g$ uniformly implies $$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x g(t)\,dt,$$hence $f'=g$.

Comment: Thanks David. Doesn't the linearity of D ensure that it is enough to show that if $f_n \rightarrow 0 $ and $f_n' \rightarrow g$ then $g=0$?. If this was the case then for any $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $f_n' \rightarrow g$ we get that $f_n-f \rightarrow 0$ and $(f_n -f)'=f_n'-f' \rightarrow g-f' \Rightarrow g-f'=0.$

Comment: @Martiny Hmm, that seems right. Curious that nobody ever states the Closed Graph Theorem that way...

Answer (score 1):

Your space $X$ is contained in the Fréchet space $Y=\{f\in C[0,1]: f|_{[0,1)} \in C^1[0,1)\}$ which is endowed with the semi-norms $\|f\|_n=\sup\{|f(x)|: x\in[0,1]\}+\sup\{|f'(x)|: x\in[0,1-1/n]\}$. Clearly, $Y$ is continuously embedded in the Banach space $Z=C[0,1]$ and since $X$ is closed there it is also closed in $Y$. The closed graph theorem implies that the topologies of $Y$ and $Z$ coincide on $X$. This implies the continuity of $X\to C[0,a]$, $f\mapsto f'|_{[0,a]}$.